# Collision error

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, collision

So I have been just playing around with the HTML canvas element and I have come across a slight problem. When player(1) lands on player2, player2 shrinks then lands on top of player(1). I am not sure how this is happening and have looked around for help but just can't seem to get it working. Any help is appreciated :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Battle</title>
 <style>
  #mycanvas {
   outline: 1px solid #000;
  }
  
 </style>
 </head>

 <body>
  <canvas id="mycanvas" width="1280" height="750"></canvas>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  
  window.cancelRequestAnimFrame = ( function() { return window.cancelAnimationFrame || window.webkitCancelRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozCancelRequestAnimationFrame || window.oCancelRequestAnimationFrame || window.msCancelRequestAnimationFrame || clearTimeout })();
  
   var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
   var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   
   var gameLive = false;
   
   var init;
   
   var friction = 0.85;
   var gravity = 2;
   
   var Blue = 0;
   var Orange = 0;
   
   var keys = [];
   
   
   
   
   var player = {
    color: "#CBE86B",
    x: 50,
    y: 100,
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    velX: 0,
    velY: 0,
    speed: 12,
    jumping: false,
    grounded: false,
    draw: function() {
     ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
     ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
   }
   
   
   var player2 = {
    color: "#F2E9E1",
    x: 1150,
    y: 100,
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    velX: 0,
    velY: 0,
    speed: 12,
    jumping: false,
    grounded: false,
    draw: function() {
     ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
     ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
   }
   
   
   var background = {
    color: "#1C140D",
    width: canvas.width,
    height: canvas.height,
    draw: function() {
     ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
     ctx.fillRect(0,0,this.width, this.height);
    }
   }
   
   function update() {
    init = requestAnimationFrame(update);
    
    if (keys[68]) { // right
     if (player.velX < player.speed) {
     player.velX+=10;
     }
    }
    if (keys[65]) { // left
     if (player.velX > -player.speed) {
      player.velX-= 10;
     }
    }
    if (keys[87]) { // jump
     if (!player.jumping && player.grounded) {
      player.jumping = true;
      player.grounded = false;
      player.velY = -player.speed*4;
     }
    }
    if (keys[37]) { // left arrow
     if (player2.velX > -player2.speed) {
      player2.velX -= 10;
     }
    }
    if (keys[39]) {
     if (player2.velX < player2.speed) {
      player2.velX += 10;
     }
    }
    if (keys[38]) {
     if (!player2.jumping && player2.grounded) {
      player2.jumping = true;
      player2.grounded = false;
      player2.velY = -player2.speed * 4;
     }
    }
    if (keys[32]) {
     
    }
    
    
    //   Can you handle the gravity of this code bit
    
    player.velX *= friction;
    
    player.velY += gravity;
    
    player.x += player.velX;
    player.y += player.velY;
    
    player.grounded = false; // fix bounce off sides of platforms
    
    player2.velX *= friction;
    
    player2.velY += gravity;
    
    player2.x += player2.velX;
    player2.y += player2.velY;
    
    player2.grounded = false; // fix bounce off sides of platforms
    

    
    if(player.y > canvas.height  -player.height){
      player.y = canvas.height  - player.height;
      player.jumping = false;
      player.grounded = true;
    } else if (player.y <= 0 || player2.y <= 0) {
      player.y = 0;
      player.jumping = false;
      player.grounded = true;
    }
    
    if (player2.y > canvas.height  -player2.height){
      player2.y = canvas.height  - player2.height;
      player2.jumping = false;
      player2.grounded = true;
    } else if (player2.y <= 0) {
      player2.y = 0;
      player2.jumping = false;
      player2.grounded = true;
    }
    
     if (player.x >= canvas.width-player.width) {
      player.x = canvas.width-player.width;
      player.jumping = false;
      player.grounded = false;
    } else if (player.x <= 0) {
      player.x = 0;
      player.jumping = false;
      player.grounded = false;
    }
    
    if (player2.x >= canvas.width - player2.width) {
      player2.x = canvas.width-player.width;
      player2.jumping = false;
      player2.grounded = false;
    } else if (player2.x <= 0) {
      player2.x = 0;
      player2.jumping = false;
      player2.grounded = false;
    }
    
     
    
    
    var dur = colCheck(player2, player);
    
    if (dur === "l") { //actually right
       player.velX = 0;
       player2.velX = 0;
     } else if (dur === "r") { // actually left
       player.velX = 0;
       player2.velX = 0;
     } else if (dur === "b") { // top
       player.velY = 0;
       player2.velY = 0;
     } else if (dur === "t") { // bottom
       player.velY = 0;
       player2.velY = 0;
    }
    //                       Collision
    function colCheck(shapeA, shapeB) {
     // get the vectors to check against
     var vX = (shapeA.x + (shapeA.width / 2)) - (shapeB.x + (shapeB.width / 2)),
      vY = (shapeA.y + (shapeA.height / 2)) - (shapeB.y + (shapeB.height / 2)),
     // add the half widths and half heights of the objects
      hWidths = (shapeA.width / 2) + (shapeB.width / 2),
      hHeights = (shapeA.height / 2) + (shapeB.height / 2),
      colDir = null;

    // if the x and y vector are less than the half width or half height, they we must be inside the object, causing a collision
     if (Math.abs(vX) < hWidths && Math.abs(vY) < hHeights) {
    // figures out on which side we are colliding (top, bottom, left, or right)
     var oX = hWidths - Math.abs(vX),
      oY = hHeights - Math.abs(vY);
     if (oX >= oY) {
     if (vY > 0) {
      colDir = "t";
      shapeA.y += oY;
     } else {
      colDir = "b";
      shapeA.y -= oY;
     }
     } else {
      if (vX > 0) {
       colDir = "l";
       shapeA.x += oX;
     } else {
      colDir = "r";
      shapeA.x -= oX;
     }   
    }
   }
    return colDir;
   }
    //                                                                                 End Collision
    
    
    //if (Blue === 10 || Orange === 10) {
    // gameOver();
    //}
    
    canvas.width = canvas.width;
    background.draw();
    player2.draw();
    player.draw();
    
    
    function gameOver() {
    cancelRequestAnimFrame(init);
   }
   }
   update();
   
   document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
     keys[e.keyCode] = true;
     e.preventDefault();
   });
   document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
     keys[e.keyCode] = false;
     e.preventDefault();
   });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, player 2 doesn't exhibit the same problem when jumping on player 1; it could be to do with some physics calculation being done earlier for one player than another.

Comment: Yeah, I still can't figure out and it's driving me insane haha